# RxJava blockingFirst/Single returns wrong exception in JUnit 5 Retrofit Test

Tags: android, rx-java2, junit5, mockwebserver

Test below is expected to return HttpException but it returns RuntimeException instead.

```
   @Test
    fun `Server down returns 500 error`() {

        mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(500))

        val exception: Exception =
            assertThrows(
                HttpException::class.java
            ) {

                githubApi
                    .getRepoList("test")
                    .blockingFirst()

            }

        assertEquals(exception, HttpException::class)

    }
```

Log for failed test is

> INFO: MockWebServer[54339] received request: GET /users/test/repos
>   HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error Feb 07, 2020 9:20:11
>   PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer acceptConnections INFO:
>   MockWebServer[54339] done accepting connections: Socket closed Feb 07,
>   2020 9:20:11 PM
>   okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$serveConnection$$inlined$execute$1
>   runOnce INFO: MockWebServer[54339] connection from /127.0.0.1 failed:
>   java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>
> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown
>   ==> expected: com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException but was:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException

Comment: `blockingFirst` wraps checked exceptions into `RuntimeException` so you have to extract the original exception as its cause.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you very much. Can you also post it as an answer so i can accept and upvote? If it's not much of a trouble can you post how to extract it from original exception?

Answer (score 2):

As @akarnokd suggests you need to extract the cause.

```
assertEquals(exception.cause, HttpException::class)
```

alternatively you can also test this without `blockingFirst` like this:

```
githubApi
    .getRepoList("test")
    .test()
    .assertError(HttpException::class)
```

Comment: I actually do like this but i also wondered how i could it with blocking operators